# Can we show that a quantum circuit with Poly(n) gates has a Hamitonian with Poly(n) terms?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, hamiltonian-simulation

It is already known that if the Hamiltonian is a sum of Poly(N) Pauli terms, it has an efficient implementation as a quantum circuit. This should mean that the circuit can be implemented with Poly(N) gates. Is the reverse true as well? Can we show that an implementable quantum circuit has a Hamiltonian with Poly(N) terms in its decomposition?

Comment: Hi and welcome to QCSE.  Have you seen [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/is-there-a-systematic-way-how-to-generate-the-hamiltonian-from-a-given-circuit#comment22296_16040)?

Comment: See [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/what-are-examples-of-hamiltonian-simulation-problems-that-are-bqp-complete) for a construction of such a Hamiltonian. I am not sure if your question is a duplicate, but I do think the top answer answers your question: yes, the reverse is true.